# Cant import numpy on mac OSX mountain lion

Tags: python, macos, numpy, matplotlib

I've looked at all the other questions like this and they all seem to be a slight variation of this one in which I can't extract an answer for my problem.

```
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

So I installed it with homebrew into the site-packages directory. At this point in time, importing numpy worked. But then when I had trouble downloading matplotlib, I downloaded the original python 2.7 as opposed to the one that comes on Mac. Now I can't import the module unless I' in the numpy directory, and when I try to build matplotlib it can't find numpy (which is a dependency). Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Third-party add-ons ("distributions") to Python, like `numpy`, are installed to a particular instance of Python.  On OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion), the Apple-supplied Python 2.7 comes with a version of `numpy` pre-installed.  You can access that python with:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "downloaded the original python2.7", but if you installed another version of python, you would need to install another version of `numpy` using it.

Comment: Ok so could it just be that since I downloaded the new version, it has hooked that python up as a system path (sorry for incorrect terminology, I'm only a highschool student). How can I change back to running the old python when I type 'python' in terminal?

Comment: Chances are your shell PATH has been changed when you installed the new Python.  If you are using `bash` as the shell (the default on OS X), edit `.bash_profile` to remove the `PATH=/Library/Frameworks ...` and `export PATH` lines and then open a new terminal window.  Or you can just type `/usr/bin/python2.7` instead of `python`.